# WSO2 IS 5.10 Auto Unlock not working after lockout time

Tags: c#, wso2, claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.10 version and we have setup Account Locking Policy as per the following documentation:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-account-locking-due-to-failed-login-attempts/#configuring-account-locking-due-to-failed-login-attempts

I am able to get Lockout Time as per rules given. But after lockout time out Account is not getting unlock automatically.
Can any one suggest why auto unlock is not working.

Comment: How do you check the account's unlock state? Is it by checking the `accountLock` claim value of the user? Does your account get unlocked at the first successful login attempt after the unlock period?

Comment: I am using the claim http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked and set as default to check in default profile. Also use http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime claim to view unlock time. Will account get unlocked if we login post unlock period? Since we are using custom message in UI after calling the scim API to see the status. Since status return locked so we do not send for login and show the message. Is that the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking the account lock state using the user's `accountLock` claim, you won't see that value set to false automatically after the lockout period.
The claim value will be set to false at the next successful login attempt after the lockout period.

By using the [account lock service](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/handler/event/account/lock/service/AccountLockService.java) you can check whether the user account is locked or not.

Refer service impl: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/blob/9e98b129fc733aa467e00485d551dfb1016151c7/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/handler/event/account/lock/service/AccountLockServiceImpl.java#L46-L60

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got what I was missing. One more query. I have used customizing Forgot Password by calling again scim api if account is locked by wrong attempts and then Lock out time is not crossed then user can use forced reset password to unlock account. My question is if lockout time is over and then will reset password can unlock the account if user reset password or still need to use forced reset password?